# Using CRT ( or not ) solve the modular system.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Using CRT or not solve the following:
$$\begin{cases} x \equiv 19 \mod 49 \\ x \equiv 10 \mod 14 \end{cases} $$
And now, I don't know how to deal with it.
Please help me.

Comment: It can't be applied because $49$ and $14$ are not co-prime!

Comment: You are right. And thats a problem which we should deal!
Eventually, we haven't to use CRT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first equation implies $x \equiv 5 \pmod 7$, while the second one implies $x \equiv 3 \pmod 7$. Therefore there is no solution to this set of congruences.